Changing class attributes through js
.cards {
    width: 'window.screen.height / 15 or whatever' + px;
    height: '.cards.width * 1.5' + px;
}

I have this code, I want to set the width of the cards class to a percent of the screen size in some way.
I don't want to edit the size of each individual element of the class because I think it would take more processing power. Instead, I want to change the entire class so that the next element I create for that class will have these updated attributes, is there any easy way to do this?
I tried inserting a script tag in the style sheet, but that just made me feel stupid so I asked chatGPT and it couldn't understand what the problem was, so I got no help there either.

Does this help in any way?

Does this answer your question? Changing element style attribute dynamically using JavaScript

Or perhaps this? SCSS How to define dynamic styles - although this will require using a Sass compiler.

The CSS answer is almost certainly what you need.  But if for some reason, you really need to do this in JS, then JS's prototypal inheritance already works that way (and the class syntax is only a thin wrapper around this.)  If in some Resize Observer you update the height and width values of your BaseCard object, and your Cards are created as const myCard = Object.create(BaseCard) (or some extend-based alternative), then on the next render, all these Card objects will have the correct values.

You can just use CSS:
.cards {
    width: calc(100vh / 15);
    aspect-ratio: 2 / 3;
}

vh is 1 percent height of viewport (vw 1 % of width of viewport)

Summary
With my answer, I primarily aim to provide an answer to the real question: how can we modify certain parts of CSS using JavaScript. However, for querying the screen height as exemplified in the question, this wouldn't be necessary either: if this is all you need, utilize the "vh" value mentioned in other answers; therefore, for full screen, use "100vh".
Solution
Although the current task (querying screen height) is achievable using just CSS too, it's not impossible to modify CSS with JavaScript. In fact, you can introduce variables in CSS as well, which you can later manipulate.
In setting the height of .cards, you reference the width settings of .cards, which fundamentally could be resolved using CSS variables.
CSS variables are always denoted with two hyphens: --variableName or --variable-name. You can reference variables using the var() function.
You can perform calculations using the calc() function.
.cards {
    --width: calc(100vh / 15); 
    width: var(--width);
    height: calc(var(--width) * 1.5);
}


Using CSS custom properties (variables) - MDN Docs
CSS: var() - MDN Docs
CSS: calc() - MDN Docs

In JavaScript, you have the ability to modify the values of CSS variables. You can assign variables either to the global  element using :root, or to specific elements as local variables. Then, you can query the respective elements using JavaScript and manipulate the value associated with the variable by modifying the style="..." attribute of the element.
// document.documentElement = get <html> element
// .style = get <html style="...">
// .setProperty = change a CSS property in style="..."
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--screen-height', newHeight + 'px');

// document.getElementById('example') = get <div id="example"> element
// .style = get <div id="example" style="...">
// .setProperty = change a CSS property in style="..."
document.getElementById('example').style.setProperty('--screen-height', newHeight + 'px');


HTMLElement: style property - MDN Docs
CSSStyleDeclaration: setProperty() method - MDN Docs
CSSStyleDeclaration: removeProperty() method - MDN Docs

Example


function changeScreenHeightTo (newHeight) {
  // inside the <html style="..."> tag, we input the value --screen-height: newHeight;, thereby overriding the default value (100px) from the CSS file
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--screen-height', newHeight + 'px');
}

function resetScreenHeight () {
  // remove the value <html style="--screen-height: example;"> from the style, thus restoring the default declaration --screen-height: 100px; in the CSS file
  document.documentElement.style.removeProperty('--screen-height');
}

function changeBackgroundColorTo (newColor) {
  // inside the <html style="..."> tag, we input the value --background-color: newColor;, thereby overriding the default value (red) from the CSS file
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--background-color', newColor);
}

function resetBackgroundColor () {
  // remove the value <html style="--background-color: example;"> from the style, restoring the default declaration --background-color: red; in the CSS file
  document.documentElement.style.removeProperty('--background-color');
}
:root {
    --screen-height: 100px;
    --background-color: red;
}

.cards {
    --cards-width: calc(var(--screen-height) / 15);
    --cards-height: calc(var(--cards-width) * 1.5);
    width: var(--cards-width);
    height: var(--cards-height);
    aspect-ratio: 2 / 3;
    background-color: var(--background-color);
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 5px;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="cards"></div>
  <div class="cards"></div>
  <div class="cards"></div>
  <div class="cards"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <button onclick="changeScreenHeightTo(window.screen.height)">
    Change --screen-height variable to window.screen.height
  </button>

  <button onclick="changeScreenHeightTo(567)">
    Change --screen-height variable to 567px
  </button>
  
  <button onclick="resetScreenHeight()">
    Reset --screen-height (remove local value)
  </button>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <button onclick="changeBackgroundColorTo('green')">
    Change --background-color variable to green
  </button>

  <button onclick="changeBackgroundColorTo('#555')">
    Change --background-color variable to #555
  </button>
  
  <button onclick="resetBackgroundColor()">
    Reset --background-color (remove local value)
  </button>
</div>




Instead, I want to change the entire class so that the next element I create for that class will have these updated attributes, is there any easy way to do this?

The attached example also clearly demonstrates that we declared the global parameter. This only needs to be modified once, and thus the class (.cards) using the variable immediately updates, consequently, every div that utilizes this class also updates.
